# In Spring Oauth2 @EnableResourceServer how can I add role based request matchers

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to give role based authorization for resources. It works with out roles if I do it like

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatcher(new OrRequestMatcher(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/hello"),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/user")
                ))
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)
            throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("openid");
    }

}
```

If I use below method it won't work for test resources.

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
                .requestMatcher(new OrRequestMatcher(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/hello"),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/user")
                ))
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/test").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
    }
```

It completely ignores token based authorization. How can I implement this? Another issue I am getting is if I remove `requestMatcher` block, Oauth client can not get the authorization code, after submitting user credentials to login form it reloads login page again. But with the previous block of code it works fine. What I am doing wrong here?

Here is my security configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/hello")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use roles in spring you have to use prefix ROLE (for example ROLE_ADMIN) to make it work with default settings.

Comment: No it won't work if I do so I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: role should not start with 'ROLE_' since it is automatically inserted. Got 'ROLE_ADMIN'`